# How to add file/camera uploading ability to Turbolinks 5 running on android?

Tags: android, webview, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

Nothing happens when you try to upload files using the turbolinks-android package.  Presumably, this is because you're expected to write your own file uploader handler?

How can this be done? I'd like the user to be able to press the upload button and then take a photo and attach that to the HTML file field.

Also, how would this be done on turbolinks-ios?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a WebChromeClient to the Turbolinks webview. Note that the given example is for API21+, lower api's use different functions when a file upload button is clicked in the webview.

Add this to the top of your file:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
private final static int REQUESTCODE_FILEPICKER = 100; // or any other int
```

And add this to your onCreate() function:

```
TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this).getWebView().setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("application/pdf");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a file"), REQUESTCODE_FILEPICKER);

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Finally: add this to your onActivityResult() function to handle the uploaded file:

```
  if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_FILEPICKER) {
        if (data == null ) {
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            mUploadMessage = null;
            return;
        }
        String dataString = data.getDataString();
        if (dataString != null) {
            Uri[] results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadMessage = null;
            return;
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
        return;
    }
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: note that you have to set i.setType to "image/*" to add the ability to upload images. In my case it is a filepicker to select pdf files.